How to run a Python script in “eww.yuck” as “deflisten” on NixOS?
I'm trying to setup notifications using eww on NixOS and have succeeded in making eww show a window in the top left using this code (eww.yuck config file):
(defwindow notifications
           :monitor 0
           :geometry (geometry :x "0px"
                               :y "0px"
                               :anchor "top right")
           :stacking "overlay"
           (label :text "Hello World"))

I also have a python script that creates a notification and outputs it to the terminal.
However to run the python script I use a flake.nix file for dependencies, so to run the script I first need to type nix develop and only then can I type python main.py and have the script work.
Now since I am trying to create a deflisten on the script like so:
(deflisten notifs :initial "a"
        "python ~/.config/eww/main.py")

(defwindow notifications
           :monitor 0
           :geometry (geometry :x "0px"
                               :y "0px"
                               :anchor "top right")
           :stacking "overlay"
           (label :text notifs))

What happens when I try to run eww open notifications is the script doesn't find the dependencies, here is the eww logs:

I've also just noticed that when I run nix develop and then eww open notifications in the "correct" directory I get this behaviour:

eww seems to just kill itself as soon as I run everything in the config directory.

please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead
